# ShowViewModel does not work if called too early

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, mvvmcross

In `MvvmCross` 4.1.4 for `Window Universal App` (UWP) platform, if we call `ShowViewModel` too early within `ViewModel` (like in `Constructor`, `Init`, or `Start` event) then it does not navigate to another model.

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
  public FirstViewModel()
  {
     ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>();
  }
}
```

Note that it works just fine for `iOS` and `Android` platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of `MvvmCross` (according to this https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1223).

The work around solution is to trigger the navigation from some events like `View_Loaded` or `View_GotFocus` within the View:

```
  public sealed partial class FirstView : MvxWindowsPage
  {
            public FirstView()
            {            
                this.InitializeComponent();
                this.Loaded += FirstView_Loaded;
            }

            private void FirstView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {   
                var viewModel = base.ViewModel as FirstViewModel
                if (viewModel != null)
                {
                    viewModel.Initialise();
                }
            }
 }
```

`ViewModel` updated:

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
  public FirstViewModel()
  {
  }

  public void Initialise()
  {
     //Navigate here
     ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not really a bug. You are trying to navigate away from a ViewModel while you are currently loading a ViewModel. This is not a good way to do things like these. You should hint the presenter to go somewhere else instead of having an middle-man ViewModel navigate somewhere else before showing itself.

Comment: Because the platforms behave differently.